# Do not load VS packages under the experimental instance

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix, vs-extensibility, vspackage

I have installed a package in VS 2010 using the regpkg.exe utility.

When I launch the **Experimental instance** using the switch /rootsuffix Exp the package is loaded.

I would like to disable the package only for the experimental instance

Even if I delete the package registration from the registry (10.0Exp and 10.0Exp_Config) when I launch the experimental instance again the registry keys are restores and the package is loaded. It seems that the registry keys in the experimental instance are inherited from the main instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case - check your custom package class attributes - to ensure whether they use values related Exp hive. Maybe there are some attributes pointing to main hive by mistake.